# открывается и сразу ищезает QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

Я меня есть функция  которая  должна  открыть виджет. Но  виджет открывается на секунду и исчезает.

Как  сделать  задержку?

```
void StudyTests::teacherEnter()
{
    TeacherWidget teacherWidget;
    teacherWidget.show();
}
```

И если совсем уже по норм сделать, то мне нужно чтобы он перерисовался в этом виджете главном mMainWidget

UPD:
Смотрите я в  main widget создал функцию:

```
void MainWidget::setTeacher()
{
     mTeacherWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
     QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
     vLayout->addWidget(mTeacherWidget);
     setLayout(vLayout);
}
```

а в стади тест:

```
void StudyTests::teacherEnter()
{
    mMainWidget->setTeacher();
}
```

а в течерентервиджете когда я  нажмаю кнопку:

```
void TeacherEnterMenuWidget::teacherEnterClicked()
{
    emit teacherEnter();
    close();
}
```

так можно  делать? А  то оно ничего не происходит

Comment: Вы его создаете на стеке, он удаляется при выходе из функции. Объявляйте как указатель

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я  сделал UPD. Но ничего не происходит

Comment: TeacherWidget* teacherWidget = new TeacherWidget(this);